# Passing values to a ASP page on page call other than QueryString

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a application where values are passed to a asp page by QueryString as shown in the code below, this call is done from JavaScript function. Now I need to pass the same values to the asp page without the use of QueryString,  is it possible to pass the values to start.asp page using anything other than QueryString?

```
location.href = "start.asp" +
              "?var1=" + someval1+
              "&var2=" + someval2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include in your page a small form:-

```
<form id="frmStart" method="POST" action="start.asp" style="display:none">
    <input name="var1" />
    <input name="var2" />
</form>
```

Your code would then be:-

```
 var frmStart = document.getElementById("frmStart");
 frmStart.var1.value = "val1";
 frmStart.var2.value = "val2";
 frmStart.submit();
```

The "start.asp" would the access the posted values as:-

```
 Dim var1 : var1 = Request.Form("var1")
 Dim var2 : var2 = Request.Form("var2")
```

If the list of possible variables is itself dynamic then you could use some javascript to create the form dynamically.

```
function post (url, data)
{
    var frmStart = document.createElement("form");
    document.body.appendChild(frmStart);
    frmStart.action = "start.asp";
    frmStart.method = "POST";
    foreach (var name in data)
    {
        var inp = document.createElement("input");
        inp.name = name;
        inp.value = data[name];
        frmStart.appendChild(inp);
    }
    frmStart.submit();
} 

post("start.asp", {var1: "val1", var2: "val2"} );
```

Comment: @AnthonyWJines: in my case I have a .htm page having a button on click of which will call a JavaScript function which will change the location.herf to navigate to start.asp page. The function worked great Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The only two methods for sending values are `GET` (QueryString) or `POST`. 
You can make a post call easily in JavaScript or more easily with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post("start.asp", { var1: "val1", var2: "val2" } );
```

Comment: Does the JQuery .post navigate away from the current page to the "start.asp" page as the code in the question does?

Comment: @Anthony no it would do it via AJAX. However it would be a simple matter to add a `success` handler to the ajax request which redirects the user, or displays a messages on failure.

Comment: @Rory: Redirects the user to where? the Start.asp page again?  So the start.asp would need to store the initial values in the POST somewhere so that they can be retrieved on a subsequent GET from the redirect.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: You are right! But the question is about how to pass values to other page. I'm not sure what the OP is trying to accomplish or trying to hide. +1 your answer to bring harmony to the universe.